# Get/display Page ID - Confluence Internal Code

Tags: javascript, html, confluence

I am trying to display a page's ID within itself i.e. within the content of the page the page ID is displayed.

Q/A within the community recommend using `**$content.getIdAsString()**` but that has not worked. I've tried to input this within an HTML macro and without one as well but to no avail. 
I'm trying to get the ID of the page so that an HTML code block could reference the page it is included on instead of inputting the page ID by hand every single time.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
<input type="image" src="/download/attachments/171705685/BackPurple.jpg" 
onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;"> 

<input type="image" src="/download/attachments/171705685/DownloadPurple.jpg" 
onclick="location.href='/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.acti‌on?pageId=17170615‌​3';"> <-- This pageID
```

I want this highlighted `pageID` is what I am hoping can be pulled in automatically

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: without you posting some code it's going to be very difficult to help you.

Comment: your code, please

Comment: Understood. Here is the code that I am currently using:

`<input type="image" src="/download/attachments/171705685/BackPurple.jpg" onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;">
<input type="image" src="/download/attachments/171705685/DownloadPurple.jpg" onclick="location.href='/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=**171706153**';"> `

the last highlighted pageID is what I am hoping can be pulled in automatically

Comment: The user has not added the code on the first occasion. I have found the code in one of the comments by the user so I have added the code which user had added in the comment section.   User Need to get the `pageID` so also highlight that too.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get the Page ID of a page do my users to have to go looking for it.

```
<tr>
<td>UNDERLYING PAGE ID:</td>
<td> $content.getId()  </td>
</tr>
```